# Many levels of categories in symfony route rule

Tags: symfony1, routes

I want to create a symfony route rule where can have one o many levels, but just es important the last one. For better explanation, here is a ¨example¨:

```
home_category:
  url:   /:sf_culture/:category1/:category2/:category3/:category4/:slug
  class: sfCategoryRoute
  param: { module: category, action: index }
  requirements:
    sf_culture: (?:es|en)
```

:category[n] are dinamics, can come one o many, and the last is the important to me. Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was extending sfRequestRoute, and overwrite the matchesUrl method, like that:

```
public function matchesUrl($url, $context = array())
{
    $url_tmp = explode('/', substr($url, 1));
    $url = (count($url_tmp)>1) ? '/'.$url_tmp[0].'/'.end($url_tmp) : $url ;

    if (false === $parameters = parent::matchesUrl($url, $context))
    {
        return false;
    }
....
```

so, the rule /:category catch /category1/category2 and /category1 and category1/category2/category3, ect.

be careful with that, because this rule also catch all routes in your aplication, you need apply extra validation inside the method before return the parameters.

Thanks for you reply anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might do the trick:

```
home_category_1:
  url:   /:sf_culture/:category1/:slug
  param: { module: category, action: index }
home_category_2:
  url:   /:sf_culture/:category1/:category2/:slug
  param: { module: category, action: index }
home_category_3:
  url:   /:sf_culture/:category1/:category2/:category3/:slug
  param: { module: category, action: index }
home_category_4:
  url:   /:sf_culture/:category1/:category2/:category3/:category4/:slug
  param: { module: category, action: index }
```

... same module/action matched to each possible URL pattern. If the URL needs to be very many levels deep, I'd probably think of turning the middle part into a single variable, but maybe someone else has a more elegant solution.